# Globally defined variable not being found in JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I cant seen to find out what Im doing wrong

```
var newcustomerform = $('#newcustomerform');

//hide new customer form
function hideForm(){
    newcustomerform.hide();
}

$(function(){
hideForm(); //this doesnt work
});
```

Whats the issue here?

Comment: `$('#newcustomerform')` is only correctly filled after the DOM is ready. Check `$('#newcustomerform').length` - if it's 0, you have a JQuery object that does not point to a DOM element.

Comment: What's calling this script?

Answer (score 0):

You must wait for the DOM to load before trying to point to a DOM element. To do that, put `var newcustomerform = $('#newcustomerform');` inside the `$(function(){`
i.e. just above where you call `hideForm()`